# Colorize dhtmlxSidebar

Tags: sidebar, dhtmlx

I have 2 dhtmlxSidebars like in a sample
[here](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxSidebar/samples/05_inside_components/04_in_sidebar.html)
How can I set a different background color to the nested one?
If I add css

```
.dhxsidebar_side {
    background-color: # 427C9C !important;
}
```

it apply changes for both backgrounds…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case the main one will be first element [0] and nested - second [1]:
(i've set different blue colors)

```
document.getElementsByClassName("dhxsidebar_side")[0].style.backgroundColor = "#add8e6";
document.getElementsByClassName("dhxsidebar_side")[1].style.backgroundColor = "#d5f2fc";
```

Also you can apply simple and selected items bg color the next way:

```
.dhxsidebar_item {
background-color: #ffffff !important;
}
.dhxsidebar_item_selected {
background-color: #b5deff !important;
}
```